# Optional Arguments in Argparse

Tags: python, exception, command-line-arguments, argparse, optional-arguments

How can I generate an error message if fewer than required optional arguments are passed in the command line while using argparse in code? for example, I have 5 optional arguments and I want to generate an error message if fewer than 4 optional arguments are used at any time.
My beginner brain can't figure this out.

```
import argparse
import math
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Loan Calculator')
parser.add_argument('--type', type=str)
parser.add_argument('--principal', type=int)
parser.add_argument('--periods', type=int)
parser.add_argument('--interest', type=float)
parser.add_argument('--payment', type=int)
args = parser.parse_args()
```

Comment: You need at least four, but there it doesn't matter which four of the five you get? I'm not sure there's support for that (it seems impossible to properly display in a standard command-line usage format without making it *crazy* verbose specifying each legal combination of 4+). I think you're stuck testing manually, possibly [using `argparse`'s help printing facilities](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#printing-help) to assist with producing the usage message.

Comment: It doesn't matter which four. if there are lesser than four arguments passed in the command line, it should display ' Incorrect Parameters'. 
I had that idea of specifying all possible combinations but i thought there can be a easier way.

Comment: `if len([k for k,v in args.__dict__.items() if v is not None]) < 4:`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is something that's most simply handled after you've called `parse_args`. Count how many of the options still have the default value of `None`. If there's more than 1, raise an error.

```
args = parser.parse_args()
if 1 < sum(1 for x in [args.type, args.principal, args.periods, args.interest, args.payment] if x is None):
    sys.exit("Too few options specified")
```